# Combining multiple features with svm

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, svm, libsvm

I want to combine [Histogram of oriented gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) and [Local Binary Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) using [Support Vector Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine). But, the features are of different dimensions. How can I combine them?

Comment: Can you provide more details? (maybe thru example data) and what have you tried?

Comment: Why not simply normalize both vectors and concatenate them?

Comment: @greeness I have HOG(Histogram of oriented gradients) and LBP(Local Binary Pattern) features. HOG features are of size 4608*no of images and LBP features are of size 7424*no of images. I want to learn one SVM(support vector machine) classifier using both the features. But, since they are of different sizes, I can't directly combine them to learn one classifier. How should I proceed?

Comment: @nikie The features are already normalized. Moreover, normalization will not have any impact on dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nikie's comment above is correct: you can just concatenate the features. So for each data point(image), the feature vector will look like this:

[HOG1, HOG2, ..., HOG4608, LBP1, LBP2, ..., LBP7424]

where HOGn is the n-th feature in the HOG features etc.

Your dataset will then be of size (no of images, 4608+7424).

Comment: Thanks..... How to combine linearSVM and Non-linear SVM output with equal weight?

Comment: I am asking under an old thread, but I wonder, in this case, all HOG1,...,HOGN and LBP1,...,LBPM features are all vector values, themselves, concatenated into much larger vector. Is that right?